# Groovy Script for JIRA-actions

Tags: groovy, jira

Нужна помощь по написанию `groovy` скрипта. Необходим скрипт, который устанавливает исполнителя по задаче, если при создании задачи исполнитель не указан. Как смог написал, но он не работает.

```
if (issue.assignee == null) {
  issue.setassigneeID("admin")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необязательно для такой простой вещи писать Groove-скрипт
В настройках проекта в `Users and Roles` вы можете указать опцию `Default Assignee`, и все задачи без исполнителя будут ставиться на выбранного пользователя.

А на будущее, для отладки Groovy-скриптов, в том же Script Runner'е есть консоль.
Чтобы получить там `issue`, надо сделать вот так:

```
def issue = issueManager.getIssueObject('ISSUE_ID')
```

Comment: к сожалению, Вы неправы. Если указать пользователя, то все задачи будут назначаться на него. 
И задача немного изменилась.   
То что есть консоль, знаю.

Comment: Если вы явным образом укажете ассигнера при создании задачи, то задача не будет ставиться на дефолтного.